# How to send sms to a twilio number

Tags: api, twilio, sms

I have configured a twilio number. Now I want to send an SMS from rest API to this twilio number. An incoming message to a twilio number. I am very new to twilio. So any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you have a Twilio number you can send messages *from* the Twilio number using the REST API. You would normally receive messages sent *to* the Twilio number from users using their messaging app on their mobile device.

To understand further I recommend you follow some Twilio tutorials:

- Here is a [quickstart guide for sending and receiving SMS with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/java)
- A guide on [sending SMS messages with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages?code-sample=code-send-an-sms-message&code-language=Java&code-sdk-version=8.x)
- The [API's Message resource reference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource)
- An [overview of TwiML and receiving messages sent to your Twilio number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/twiml)

Hopefully they get you started on a path to understanding.

Comment: Thanks philnash. I am looking at some API or provision to send sms TO a twilio number not FROM.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your use case. Could you explain further?